# JQuery Show and hide in multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $("#infocontent").hide();
    $("#infocontent div").hide();       
    $('#linkwrapper a[id]').click(function(){            
        var vsubmen = this.id +"content";              
        if( $("#infocontent").is(":visible") == false ) {
            $("#" + vsubmen).show('fast',function() {
                $("#infocontent").slideDown();
            });
        } else if ( $("#" + vsubmen).is(":visible") == false ) {
            $("#infocontent").slideUp('slow',function(){
                $("#infocontent div").hide();
                $("#" + vsubmen).show();
                $("#infocontent").slideDown('slow');    
            });
        } else {
            $("#infocontent").slideUp('slow',function(){
                $("#infocontent div").hide();
            });
        }
        return false;
    });    
});
```

HTML

This one shows and close as well

```
<div id="wirelessc">                        
    <div id="linkwrapper">
    <a id="link1" href="#">Configuración del AP (Punto de Acceso)</a><br/>
    <a id="link2" href="#">link2</a><br/>
    <a id="link3" href="#">link3</a>
</div>

<div id="infocontent">
    <div id="link1content"><p>1° Paso: Conectamos el Router a la PC, luego de esto ingresamos a nuestro navegador y 
                        tipeamos“192.168.1.1” en el buscador  e inmediatamente nos saltara una ventana que pedirá 
                        el nombre de usuario y contraseña de nuestro Router.
    </p></div>
    <div id="link2content">Information about 2.</div>
    <div id="link3content">Information about 3.</div>
```

---

It shows when u click but doesn't close when u open others

---

```
<div id="bridge">
    <div id="linkwrapper">
        <a id="link4" href="#">Configuración del APPPPPPP (Punto de Acceso)</a><br/>
        <a id="link5" href="#">link2</a><br/>
        <a id="link6" href="#">link3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="infocontent">
        <div id="link4content"><p>1° Paso: Conectamos el Router a la PC, luego de esto ingresamos a nuestro navegador y 
                        tipeamos“192.168.1.1” en el buscador  e inmediatgsdgsdgsgsgsamente nos saltara una ventana que pedirá 
                        el nombre de usuario y contraseña de nuestro Router.
        </p></div>
        <div id="link5content">Information about 2.</div>
        <div id="link6content">Information about 3.</div>
    </div>                          
</div>
```

Boths divs are in the same html file

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Don't use two elements with the same id in the same html document (for linkwrapper and infocontent). I encourage you to use class instead in such a situation.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eDMEG/) is a jsfiddle with your code, can you explain what is wrong?

Comment: Also, remember to indent your code &mdash; it's extremely hard to read, so I have taken the liberty to format it properly.

Comment: second div doesn't close automatically

Comment: Which div are you referring to exactly, and what exactly do you want it to do? and when? I see all the `link[number]content` stuff disappear when another pops up..

Comment: you do have multiple ID's so when you use a jquery select based on the ID it will only find the first element with that ID... you can change to a class and select like `$(".infocontent")` for example

Answer (score 0):

Apart from few missing closing div tags, I didn't see anything wrong in your. 
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/XE6z9/) is a link of your code, where show/hide works fine.

```
   <div id="wirelessc">                        
    <div id="linkwrapper">
     <a id="link1" href="#">Configuración del AP (Punto de Acceso)</a><br/>
     <a id="link2" href="#">link2</a><br/>
     <a id="link3" href="#">link3</a>
    </div>

    <div id="infocontent">
    <div id="link1content">
      <p>1° Paso: Conectamos el Router a la PC, luego de esto ingresamos   nuestro navegador y 
                    tipeamos“192.168.1.1” en el buscador  e inmediatamente nos saltara una ventana que pedirá 
                    el nombre de usuario y contraseña de nuestro Router.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="link2content">Information about 2.</div>
    <div id="link3content">Information about 3.</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bridge">
  <div id="linkwrapper">
    <a id="link4" href="#">Configuración del APPPPPPP (Punto de Acceso)</a><br/>
    <a id="link5" href="#">link2</a><br/>
    <a id="link6" href="#">link3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="infocontent">
    <div id="link4content"><p>1° Paso: Conectamos el Router a la PC, luego de esto ingresamos a nuestro navegador y 
                    tipeamos“192.168.1.1” en el buscador  e inmediatgsdgsdgsgsgsamente nos saltara una ventana que pedirá 
                    el nombre de usuario y contraseña de nuestro Router.
    </p></div>
    <div id="link5content">Information about 2.</div>
    <div id="link6content">Information about 3.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: IT doesn't works for some reason, see what happens in bridge div]

http://puu.sh/5hQCn.png